# How to launch/close a program when launching/closing another program using the Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows, dropbox, scheduled-tasks

I have a Steam game which I launch in multiple ways such as:

- Clicking the play button on the Steam Library page
- Playing the game in Steam Big Picture Mode
- Manually launching the .exe
- Other batch files

Everytime I launch it, I want to close the process `dropbox.exe` and everytime I close my game, I want to launch the Dropbox program.

Given that I launch it in many different ways, a batch file to cover all cases is not possible. I have considered using the `Windows Task Scheduler` to listen to the event when the game's exe launches, but I do not know if this is possible.

**So, how do I launch/close a program when launching/closing another program using the Windows Task Scheduler?**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch in multiple ways, then you need to build checkers for each method. Why don't you just settle on one method, like a batch file and just run that from now on? In that batch file, you just stop and start dropbox as part of your batch file.